# installing headers for 3.5 kernel in debian wheezy?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, debian, nvidia

Yesterday, I compiled the 3.5 kernel in debian wheezy (testing), in a thinkpad edge S430 (i5). I did it following [this blog](http://verahill.blogspot.com.es/2012/07/compiling-kernel-35-on-debian-testing.html), with all the default options. It seems succesful, but then, I tried to install the proprietary nvidia driver with `m-a auto-install nvidia-kernel`. The install is not able to proceed until the correct headers are installed. However, I have tried both manually to install linux-headers-3.5.0-18 and the linux-headers-amd64 package, but module assistant is not able to see them, showing the following message:

> Bad luck, the kernel headers for the target kernel version could not be found and you did not specify other valid kernel headers to use.

There are other ways to install the driver, but I think that the problem with headers is broader.

Although I have been a Debian user for some years, I am far from being an expert, and I am not clear with the problems that I might face when compiling a 3.5 kernel on a Debian testing, so any help and explanation will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First run

```
sudo m-a prepare
```

> ```
> Getting source for kernel version: 3.8.5-ck1
> Kernel headers available in /usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.5-ck1
> Creating symlink..
> ```

Then do

```
sudo m-a a-i nvidia
```

and it should work.

Note that I did this on 3.8.5-ck1, but I built and installed that kernel in a similar fashion to how I wrote up the 3.5 build that you followed.